# datatables jquery - Uncaught TypeError : CAnnot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Could someone help me identify the problem with the code below.

What I am trying to do :
Using jquery/datatables, I am trying to show additional data for a particular row (retrieved using an ajax call).

Datatable definition code is :

```
$(window).load(function() {
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    //"font-size" : 2em,
    "columnDefs" : [ {
        className : "details-control",
        "targets"  : [1],
        "orderable" : false },
        {
        "targets" : [2,6],
        "width" : "25%",
        className : "dt-left"},
        { 
        "targets" : [3,4,5,7],
        "width" : "10%",
        className : "dt-center"}
        ]
   }); 
   // Add event listener for opening and closing details
   $('#table_id').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
       var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var row = table.row( tr );

       if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
       //This row is already open - close it
           row.child.hide();
           tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
        //Open this row
            row.child(formatx(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }

});
```

});

The formatx function and the the callback function are :

```
    function printd(data) {
            var pdata = '';
            for(var i in data.careGivers){
                pdata = pdata + '<tr>'+
                    '<td>Parent: </td>'+
                    '<td>'+data.careGivers[i].ParentName+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
                }
                pdata =  '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+pdata+
        '</table>';
                alert(pdata);
                return pdata;
            }

function formatx(d) {

    var val = d[0];
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('Sclass/get_wl_details_ajax/')?>/"+val,
        dataType:'json',
        success : printd
    });
}
```

The error i get (because of which no data is displayed, I assume) is :
[image]

Comment: `formatx(row.data())` returns json, correct?

Comment: @DelightedD0D - Yes that is correct. Verified that

Comment: Can you show the format?

Comment: The [example here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) seems to indicate that `row.child().show()` expects html, still looking through the docs to see if json is accepted

Comment: The printd function returns an html string, which is what I am expecting to be processed by the show function.

Comment: Can you add `var test = formatx(row.data())`  right above `row.child(formatx(row.data())).show();` and tell me what the value is for `test`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D - test returns 'undefined'. Correct me, but what I need is a way to allow show to do its work, only after the async call has completed. 
Your recommendation below made sense, but did not work...i tried it.

Comment: ahhh, yes that is correct, give me just a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your function `formatx(d)` calls `printd(data)` which creates `html` and returns it to `formatx(d)` **but** `formatx(d)` doesnt return anything.

You need to return the result back to the `row.child(formatx(row.data())).show();` call. Additionally, your `formatx()` uses an ajax call meaning that the returned value will not be immediately available so your logic will have to account for that.

There are at least 2 methods I can think of (many more out there and possibly better).

#### Method 1

Pass `row` through your chain of functions and then call `row.child(someData).show();` only at the end of the logic something like this:

```
  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
 $('#table_id').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
     var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     var row = table.row(tr);

     if (row.child.isShown()) {
         //This row is already open - close it
         row.child.hide();
         tr.removeClass('shown');
     } else {
         //Open this row
         formatx(row) // just pass row to the format function here
         tr.addClass('shown');
     }

 });

 function formatx(row) {
     var val = row.data()[0]; //slight change here
     $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo site_url('Sclass/get_wl_details_ajax/')?>/" + val,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (response) { // change this callback to return the result
             return printd(response,row);
         }
     });
 }

function printd(data,row) {
     var pdata = '';
     for (var i in data.careGivers) {
         pdata = pdata + '<tr>' +
             '<td>Parent: </td>' +
             '<td>' + data.careGivers[i].ParentName + '</td>' +
             '</tr>';
     }
     pdata = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' + pdata +
         '</table>';
     alert(pdata);
     row.child(formatx(row.data(pdata))).show();
 }
```

#### Methd 2

Merge all of the functionality into one block and let the ajax success callback handle the issue for you, something like this (which is a bit cleaner if you dont need to call those functions from elsewhere in your code):

```
 // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#table_id').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row(tr);

      if (row.child.isShown()) {
          //This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
      } else {
          var val = row.data()[0]; 
          $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url('Sclass/get_wl_details_ajax/')?>/" + val,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                  var pdata = '';
                  for (var i in data.careGivers) {
                      pdata = pdata + '<tr>' +
                          '<td>Parent: </td>' +
                          '<td>' + data.careGivers[i].ParentName + '</td>' +
                          '</tr>';
                  }
                  pdata = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' + pdata +
                      '</table>';
                  alert(pdata);
                  row.child(row.data(pdata)).show();
                  tr.addClass('shown');
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: why are you calling `formatx` again in your second method ? `row.child(formatx(row.data(pdata))).show();`

Comment: @user5249203 Just forgot to update that line on the second example. Updated to `row.child(row.data(pdata)).show();` ty

Comment: thanks for the quick update. your solution was helpful.

Comment: Method 2 :  row.child(row.data(pdata)).show();  replace with  row.child(pdata).show();